# Getting following web services error after activating the Rewards Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, web-services

When activate "sumo reward points" plugin and run this

```
http://imexleader.com/webservice/login.php?action=login&username=sanjay&password=san123" webservice.
```

It gives me following errors:

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   function 's.t.r.r.e.v' not found or invalid function name in
>   /home/imex323/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rewardsystem/inc/class_reward_system_menus.php
>   on line 214
>
> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   function 's.t.r.r.e.v' not found or invalid function name in
>   /home/imex323/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rewardsystem/inc/class_reward_system_menus.php
>   on line 215
>
> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   function 's.t.r.r.e.v' not found or invalid function name in
>   /home/imex323/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rewardsystem/inc/class_reward_system_menus.php
>   on line 220
>
> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   no array or string given in
>   /home/imex323/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rewardsystem/inc/class_reward_system_menus.php
>   on line 221
>
> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   function 's.t.r.r.e.v' not found or invalid function name in
>   /home/imex323/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rewardsystem/inc/class_reward_system_menus.php
>   on line 222

Answer (score 0):

You have a hacked version of the plugin! Check your plugin or delete.

strrev is is php function for reversing a string, it is commonly used in hacking schemes.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php